# Push submodule git changes to server

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I have a team git repo that has a submodule. I had to go into the submodule and make changes. I push my repo to a remote server. The changes I made to the submodule are not showing up on the server. Only the non-submodule changes.

My co-worker has also made changes to the submodule. Has pushed the changes and do not show up either. Is there a specific way to push changes to a submodule? The submodule is it's own repo and is on a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are making changes in a submodule folder, you need to commit and push directly in that folder. When the submodule commit will be pushed, you will need to go to the parent folder and then make an additional commit, with the changed reference to the submodule, then push that commit.

Here is an example:

```
# current folder is parent project

cd submodule-git
# making changes in submodule 
touch new-file
git add new-file
git commit -m "new file was added"
git push origin master

cd ..
# changing reference to new commit in the parent project
git add submodule-git
git commit -m "updated submodule"
git push origin master
```

---

Sometimes you can't use the default remote URL of a submodule to push changes. For example, if you used a read-only URL, you can add an additional remote in just the submodule and use it instead of the origin. Here is an example:

```
# current folder is parent project

cd submodule-git
# adding new remote with name 'write-origin' and ssh://user@example.com/project.git
git remote add write-origin ssh://user@example.com/project.git
# making changes in submodule and creating new commit 
git push write-origin master
```